# Fitting a bottle cage

Tags: bottle

I have an old steel frame Peugot road bike that I want to fit a bottle cage to. It has braze-ons but I'm not sure how to mount it. Can anyone advise? Pictures uploaded.

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like plastic or rubber plugs in the braze-ons. Try to remove them — I think there are a threads under them.

Comment: If all else fails a couple of jubilee clips will be strong enough to hold a cage.

Comment: @constpetrov you should make your comment an answer

Comment: @constpetrov Thanks for the comments. I think you are probably right about there being threads under the black plugs. They seem really in tight - maybe just hack at them with a screwdriver to try and loosen them do you think?

Comment: @gx450 you might get an old credit card under the edge as a spudger ssuing you don't want to try a screwdriver, or try putting a small woodscrew into the bung.  The bungs have probably hardened over time and some dirt has probably got in to glue them into place.

Comment: @ChrisH Good idea - I'll try and put a screw in the plug and pull it all out together like a corkscrew!

Comment: @constpetrov - You should submit your response as an answer!

Comment: I would also clear the rust from around the braze-ons!

Comment: I'd try to use a knife as a shim around the sides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

looks like plastic or rubber plugs in the braze-ons. Try to remove them — I think there are a threads under them.

Comment: I was able to remove them. Used a knife as suggested by @Batman to prise them off then pull out with pliers. Screw threads underneath for the cage.

Comment: Other words (for the search engines to find) are  "bung"  and "grommit"